# Conversion from string to integer error in 3.5 from 4.0 .NET Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, time, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have an issue regarding the `.NET Framework`when I tried to change the .NET Framework to 4.0 to 3.5. The code works perfectly in 4.0 but when I tried to change it to 3.5 it gives me an error `Conversion from string to integer`. So how to fix this one? Below is my code:

```
  Dim counter As Integer
  ts = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

  If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
  Me.timer.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss") 'I get the error from here
  ElseIf ts.TotalMilliseconds < 0 Then

  Timer1.Interval = 500
  CountDownFrom = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5)
  TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
  Me.timer.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")

  If Me.timer.Text = "00:00" Then

  counter = counter + 1
  If counter = 1 Then
  saban()
  End If

  End If

 End If
```

Comment: you should include declaration of variables used in snippet above, especially `timer` and `ts`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslash from this line:

```
Me.timer.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
```

to make it

```
Me.timer.Text = ts.ToString("mm:ss")
```

Comment: Is Me.Timer a Timer object on the form? If so, you should read the documentation for the [Timer object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If not, then what kind of object is it?